# With system() in C++ on Windows, why are two quotes required to invoke a program in another directory?

Tags: c++, command, system, quotes

I have the find.exe program in my utils folder. This does not work:

```
system("\"utils/find.exe\"");
```

All I get is

```
'utils' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

However, for some reason this works:

```
system("\"\"utils/find.exe\"\"");
```

Echoing the single quoted string

```
system("echo \"utils/find.exe\"");
```

outputs

```
"utils/find.exe"
```

... so why do I need two quotes?

Comment: It might be fun to try and see what happens if you escape it with `^`.

Comment: When the issue is not with the forward slash, but quoting to escape spaces, see [C++ system() not working when there are spaces in two different parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9964865/2718186)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're on windows because you're trying to execute an .exe file. So, instead of writting  "utils/find.exe", try to write "utils\find.exe". The delimiting character on windows is '\', so it probably sees "utils" as a command since '/' is ignored.

Comment: This is what came to my mind. However, it would be `"utils\\find.exe"`.

Comment: Yes, on a c-string it should be \\. Have you tested it to see if it works without quotes?

Comment: Yes, the question was tagged with C++. No, I haven't tried it one way or the other. I would look for the author of the question to do that.

Comment: Oh, i'm sorry, i'm so sleepy that i didn't check your nickname and i thought that you were the author.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps `system()` is passing your command line to the shell, e.g. `cmd.exe`, which also needs quoting?

Answer (score 0):

Even though you can use both / and \ as directory separators in Windows, the command processor will try to interpret anything starting with a / as a switch. Try this:

```
system("\"utils\\find.exe\"");
```