# C++ system() not working when there are spaces in two different parameters

Tags: c++, windows, system

I'm trying to run a .exe that requires some parameters by using system().

If there's a space in the .exe's path AND in the path of a file passed in parameters, I get the following error:

```
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

Here is the code that generates that error:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main (){
    system("\"C:\\Users\\Adam\\Desktop\\pdftotext\" -layout \"C:\\Users\\Adam\\Desktop\\week 4.pdf\"");
    _getch();
}
```

If the "pdftotext"'s path doesn't use quotation marks (I need them because sometimes the directory will have spaces), everything works fine. Also, if I put what's in "system()" in a string and output it and I copy it in an actual command window, it works.

I thought that maybe I could chain some commands using something like this:

```
cd C:\Users\Adam\Desktop;
pdftotext -layout "week 4.pdf"
```

So I would already be in the correct directory, but I don't know how to use multiple commands in the same system() function.

Can anyone tell me why my command doesn't work or if the second way I thought about would work?

**Edit:** Looks like I needed an extra set of quotation marks because system() passes its arguments to cmd /k, so it needs to be in quotations. I found it here:

[C++: How to make a my program open a .exe with optional args](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7669433/c-how-to-make-a-my-program-open-a-exe-with-optional-args)

so I'll vote to close as duplicate since the questions are pretty close even though we weren't getting the same error message, thanks!

Comment: Whoever thought that putting spaces into filenames would be "a good idea" should be shot.

Comment: I guess that would be Microsoft? Lots of stuff broke when people's work wound up in `C:\Documents and Settings`.

Comment: I know, but I don't really have a choice, I have over 1000 files to parse and they all have spaces

Comment: Why use multiple commands in one `system` call? Make multiple `system` calls. `system` has to wait for the command to finish.

Comment: I thought that calling system("cd ...") and then system("pdftotext" ...) would call two different cmd windows instead of calling it in the same cmd?

Comment: @smerlin I don't know about how it works on Windows, but on *nix, that's definitely not the case because system() creates a new shell and the directory change won't bubble up.

Comment: I can't even get system("cd C:") working. If I use the cd command in system and then call dir, I'm still in the project's dir (which is on a different drive)

Comment: It works fine for me. What Windows version are you on?

Comment: @hamstergene Windows 7 Professional SP1 64bits. Which one works fine? The cd thing I posted in the comments or the example code in my post?

Comment: @AdamSmith I'm on exactly the same OS. I've tried `system()` with `exe` and `bat` files, with paths with and without spaces, they're all working.

Comment: @hamstergene I see... Are you using an exe that can take arguments that also use spaces? Because that's the problem I was having and I just found out why (needed another set of "" since the arguments are passed to cmd /k). Thanks your replies!

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++: How to make a my program open a .exe with optional args](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7669433/c-how-to-make-a-my-program-open-a-exe-with-optional-args)

Comment: @mah: you were correct that adjacent `std::system` calls use different shells (on windows aswell). I thought i already used `std::system("cd somedir")` to change the cwd of an application, but it seems like i remembered it incorrectly.

Comment: To run multiple commands, use & as the delimiter: system("cd xyzzy & dir");

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`system()` runs command as `cmd /C command`. And here's citation from `cmd` doc:

```
If /C or /K is specified, then the remainder of the command line after
the switch is processed as a command line, where the following logic is
used to process quote (") characters:

    1.  If all of the following conditions are met, then quote characters
        on the command line are preserved:

        - no /S switch
        - exactly two quote characters
        - no special characters between the two quote characters,
          where special is one of: &<>()@^|
        - there are one or more whitespace characters between the
          two quote characters
        - the string between the two quote characters is the name
          of an executable file.

    2.  Otherwise, old behavior is to see if the first character is
        a quote character and if so, strip the leading character and
        remove the last quote character on the command line, preserving
        any text after the last quote character.
```

It seems that you are hitting case 2, and `cmd` thinks that the whole string `C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\pdftotext" -layout "C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\week 4.pdf` (i.e. without the first and the last quote) is the name of executable.

So the solution would be to wrap the whole command in extra quotes:

```
//system("\"D:\\test\" nospaces \"text with spaces\"");//gives same error as you're getting
system("\"\"D:\\test\" nospaces \"text with spaces\"\""); //ok, works
```

And this is very weird. I think it's also a good idea to add `/S` just to make sure it will always parse the string by the case 2:

```
system("cmd /S /C \"\"D:\\test\" nospaces \"text with spaces\"\""); //also works
```

Comment: @AdamSmith “no /S switch” is required for case 1 to be applicable (see the doc), so it forces `cmd` to use the old behavior. No other effect is mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works great! After reading the excerpt from the documentation that you posted, you're probably right and I might be better off using /S, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I got here looking for an answer, and this is the code that I came up with (and I was this explicit for the benefit of next person maintaining my code):

```
std::stringstream ss;
std::string pathOfCommand;
std::string pathOfInputFile;

// some code to set values for paths

ss << "\"";                             // command opening quote
ss << "\"" << pathOfCommand   << "\" "; // Quoted binary (could have spaces)
ss << "\"" << pathOfInputFile << "\"";  // Quoted input (could have spaces)
ss << "\"";                             // command closing quote
system( ss.str().c_str() );             // Execute the command
```

and it solved all of my problems.

Answer (score 0):

Good learning from here on the internals of System call.Same issue reproducible(of course) with C++ string, TCHARs etc. 
One approach that always helped me is SetCurrentDirectory() call. I first set current path and then execute. This has worked for me so far. Any comments welcome.
-Sreejith. D. Menon