# Calling multiple _popen fails

Tags: c, windows, popen

I am having a problem with `_popen(const char *, const char *)`

I'm trying to use awk to get infos from adb but my program crashes at the second _popen call (the method is called twice).

Here is the problematic code (`sysinf_getvalue()` is called multiple times in the main).

---

## Ugly code

```
int deviceadbinfowritten = 0;
int devicebootloaderinfowritten = 0;
int adbinit = 0;

int initadb()
{
    if(!adbinit)
    {
        system("adb kill-server && adb start-server");
        adbinit = 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int sysinfo_getadbinfofile()
{
    if(!deviceadbinfowritten)
    {
        system("echo Please connect your device && adb wait-for-device && adb.exe shell getprop > deviceinfo");
        deviceadbinfowritten = 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

int sysinfo_getbootloaderinfofile()
{
    if(!devicebootloaderinfowritten)
    {
        system("adb wait-for-device && adb reboot bootloader && fastboot getvar all > bootloaderinfo && fastboot reboot");
        devicebootloaderinfowritten = 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

char *sysinfo_getvalue(char *key, int bootloader)
{
    initadb();
    if(bootloader) sysinfo_getbootloaderinfofile();
    else sysinfo_getadbinfofile();
    char *file = (bootloader)?"bootloaderinfo":"deviceinfo";

    char *command = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen("awk.exe -F\":\" \" { print $2 }\" < ") + strlen(key) + (bootloader)?0:2 + strlen(file)));
    char *adbkey = malloc((strlen(key)+2)* (sizeof(char)));
    if(!bootloader) sprintf(adbkey, "/%s/", key);
    sprintf(command, "awk.exe -F\":\" \"%s { print $2 }\" < %s", ((bootloader)?key:adbkey), file);

    printf("%s\n", command);
    char *pointer = exe(command);
    if(!bootloader)
    {
        pointer += 2;
        pointer[strlen(pointer)-3] = 0;
    }

    return pointer;
}

char *exe(char *exe)
{
    char buffer[1024];
    FILE *f;

    printf("debug %s\n", exe);

    f = _popen(exe, "r");

    printf("debug\n");

    char *res = NULL;

    printf("debug\n");

    if (f == NULL) {
        printf("[-] Failed to run command\n" );
        return NULL;
}
    printf("debug\n");

    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), f) != NULL) {
        if(res == NULL) {res = malloc(strlen(buffer) * sizeof(char)); strcpy(res, buffer);}
        else {res = realloc(res, strlen(res) * sizeof(char) + sizeof(buffer));sprintf(res, "%s%s", res, buffer);}
}

    printf("debug\n");

    _pclose(f);

    return res;
}
```

NOTE : If I directly call `exe()` in the main with the same string supplied _popen doesn't crash.

NOTE 2 : Debugger says `"warning: HEAP[program.exe]: 
warning: Heap block at 002D2EC0 modified at 002D2EC9 past requested size of 1"`

Comment: The code is missing error checking on system calls (like `system()`, `malloc()`). Also it does not seem to free any of the memory allocated via `malloc()`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if you are missing to allocate room for the 0-terminator.

That is the one last additional byte every character array needs if used as string to indicate the end of the string by a character of value `NUL` (decimal `0`).

At least this line:

```
char *command = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen("awk.exe -F\":\" \" { print $2 }\" < ") + strlen(key) + (bootloader)?0:2 + strlen(file)));
```

shall allocate one character more:

```
char *command = malloc(
  sizeof(char) * (
    strlen("awk.exe -F\":\" \" { print $2 }\" < ") + 
    strlen(key) + 
    (bootloader)?0:2 + strlen(file)) + 
    1
  )
);
```

(I did not check all allocations/delcaration of character arrays in your code, for issues like this.)

Comment: Oh thanks, I forgot that `strlen()` **doesn't** include the 0terminator.

Comment: The code is still crashing, tried to figure out why but I can't.

Comment: @Freesalad: You might like to check the other cases where `malloc()` gets involved. Also using `calloc()` instead might help as it inits the memory to all 0s.

Answer (score 0):

I found out in this link [C++ system() not working when there are spaces in two different parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9964865/c-system-not-working-when-there-are-spaces-in-two-different-parameters) that you need to encapsulate all your system calls with quotes if you want them to work properly.
For example in my code I need to use `exe("\"mycommand\"");` instead of `exe("mycommand");`