# Why does windows API need to pass in so many parameters?

Tags: c, windows

Why do old windows API's require you to pass so many parameters?

example(from [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15435994/how-do-i-open-a-exe-in-from-another-c-exe)) :

```
// additional information
   STARTUPINFO si;     
   PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

   // set the size of the structures
   ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
   si.cb = sizeof(si);
   ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );

  // start the program up
  CreateProcess( lpApplicationName,   // the path
    argv[1],        // Command line
    NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
    NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
    FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
    0,              // No creation flags
    NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
    NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
    &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
    &pi )           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
    ) 
    // Close process and thread handles. 
    CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
    CloseHandle( pi.hThread

);
```

Why so complicated? Every parameter is required, we do not need to force the users to pass in every parameters at once, they could be setup later, provide a "constructor" and so on.

edit : The C language doesn't support default values, so I remove this option

Comment: Check out http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window/XCreateWindow.html

Comment: There are no default parameters in C

Comment: Every one of those parameters has a specific purpose. That you're not using them means they don't fit *your* specific usage. You can always wrap them up to facilitate your needs only. That MS chose not to do that *for you* isn't a problem with the API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MS chose to provide a "small" number of very flexible APIs, allowing the programmer to do a large number of things.  If they didn't add all of those parameters, then there's various things that wouldn't be possible to do.  And remember this API is in C-  no default values (and really default values are a bad idea in such a large function call) and no classes with default constructors (hence the need to 0 out memory like in this example) that can set default values.  And in a lot of cases MS didn't want to guess on what default values should be-  they didn't know how the programmers were going to use their APIs and decided not to assume.  Its a different philosophy from today's Java based, everything's a framework, hold the newbie's hand (and handcuff the guy who actually knows what he's doing) world.

In addition in some cases they decided to make things easier for backwards compatibility-  for example the need to set si.cb to the size of the startup structure-  this is so the startup structure could be versioned (later versions would have more fields thus a different size) and it could be made to work with either version.  Of course this made the API a bit more complicated, but it made everyone happier than having all executables break every new OS.