# Runing an external program from another program Linux or cygwin

Tags: c++, windows, cygwin

I want to run a program which uses the output from another program. I tried calling `system("myfile.exe")` but the executable doesn't seem to be executed. I am using cygwin. How should I run `myfile.exe` from within my program?

Comment: Can you start myfile.exe manually, outside of the first program?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I open a .exe in from another C++ .exe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15435994/how-do-i-open-a-exe-in-from-another-c-exe)

Comment: Are you sure your program isn't running? It may just seem that way because you can't see the output.

Comment: @deviantfan yes, myfile.exe is running outside the program,

Comment: @CoffeeandCode Yes, I am sure, its not running, because output of exe file has to generate some output which is not produced.

Comment: @namanarora you glided past my exact point. Your application might not be capturing the external applications `stdout` output.

Comment: What did system() return?

Comment: I missed the complete path, its running now after adding the complete path for myfile.exe file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Cygwin using shell or bash scripts you can store the output of the first program into a variable.
For example we say that program1 is the "date" command and "echo" is the second program. In shell you use: 
`dt=```date```;`  will put the value returned by the date command into the variable dt. (grave accent executes the code and returns the output)
`echo $dt` prints the value of the variable `dt`