# Open .exe in window of another c++ program

Tags: c++, console, c++14, exe

I know how to run compiled C++ programs (exe files) from my console, but it starts only in multiple windows.

So, I would like to know how to run it in my console like in windows cmd. Is it possible ?

Comment: What do you mean by `but it starts only in multiple `?

Comment: I use ShellExecute function from Windows.h to run exe files. It starts programs in separate window from initial program

Comment: What about C's `system` from `stdlib.h`? Actually, there are a few ways to start another program, it depends on what you want to achieve.

Comment: I need to run some program in another program like in linux terminal or windows cmd

Comment: Take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15435994/how-do-i-open-an-exe-from-another-c-exe

Comment: Thanks, I know this. It runs the programs in different window, but I need in the same.

Comment: So, you want to synchronously execute a exe-file in your program and get output in the same terminal?

Comment: At last =) Yes!

Answer (score 0):

If you are beginner:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    system("Name.exe"); //This is for starting program in your programs console.
    system("start Name.exe"); //This is for starting program in its own console.
    return 0;
}
```

Note: usually programmers and antiviruses dont like `system()`, maybe because:

> - It is resource heavy
> - It defeats security -- you don't know you it's a valid command or does the same thing on every system, you could even start up programs you didn't intend to start up. The danger is that when you directly execute a program, it gets the same privileges as your program -- meaning that if, for example, you are running as system administrator then the malicious program you just inadvertently executed is also running as system administrator. If that doesn't scare you silly, check your pulse.
> - Anti virus programs hate it, your program could get flagged as a virus.

-from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15440094/12641442).

..so, you can try instead:

```
ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "Name.exe", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
```

or:

```
VOID startup(LPCTSTR lpApplicationName){
   // additional information
   STARTUPINFO si;     
   PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

   // set the size of the structures
   ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
   si.cb = sizeof(si);
   ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );

  // start the program up
  CreateProcess( lpApplicationName,   // the path
    argv[1],        // Command line
    NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
    NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
    FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
    0,              // No creation flags
    NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
    NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
    &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
    &pi             // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure (removed extra parentheses)
    );
    // Close process and thread handles. 
    CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
    CloseHandle( pi.hThread );
}
```

Note: With same `#include <iostream>`, `#include <windows.h>`, `using namespace std;` headers! In 2 last options you can change parameters to get better result.

[How do I open an .exe from another C++ .exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15435994/how-do-i-open-an-exe-from-another-c-exe?noredirect=1&lq=1)