# How to iterate over an exe file that takes arguments in cmd

Tags: c++, bash, shell

There is a program that accepts images containing license plates as arguments.
This program extracts only the license plate itself, letter and number image from the image received as an argument.
How to use this program is as follows.

```
C:\Users\gksql\Desktop\PlateRec>PlateRecog_saveDigits_Location someimage.jpg
```

This will create one image_Plate.jpg file that contains the license plate itself and several image_Digits_ (number) .jpg files that contain numbers or characters.
The problem is that the execution command itself is quite long, and there are at least a few thousand images.
That's why I want to run this PlateRecog_saveDigits_Location.exe file for all images containing license plates in any folder.
As a matter of fact, I can not change the source of the PlateRecog_saveDigits_Location file at this time.
I want to know how to iterate through all the images in a window.

Thank you for your wisdom.

Comment: I really don't see how C++ applies here unless you want to write a C++ program to do this.

Comment: C: \ Users \ gksql \ Desktop \ PlateRec> 
    PlateRecog_saveDigits_Location someimage1.jpg
    C: \ Users \ gksql \ Desktop \ PlateRec> 
    PlateRecog_saveDigits_Location someimage2.jpg
    C: \ Users \ gksql \ Desktop \ PlateRec> 
    PlateRecog_saveDigits_Location someimage3.jpg
    C: \ Users \ gksql \ Desktop \ PlateRec> 
    PlateRecog_saveDigits_Location someimage4.jpg

Someimage1, 2, 3, and 4 are all in one file. I've heard that I can run it repeatedly using a dat file. Do I need the internal structure of the PlateRecog_saveDigits_Location file to run it repeatedly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post is tagged c++, bash, shell...

looks like you want to loop through a list of files, calling the same executable if i understand correctly.  Here are some good posts to get you going.

**Loop through files in directory c++:**
[How do you iterate through every file/directory recursively in standard C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67273/how-do-you-iterate-through-every-file-directory-recursively-in-standard-c)

**Launching an executable from within a c++ project:**
[How do I open an .exe from another C++ .exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15435994/how-do-i-open-an-exe-from-another-c-exe)

**Iterating through files in directory (bash):**
[How to iterate over files in a directory with Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20796200/how-to-iterate-over-files-in-a-directory-with-bash)

**Iterating through files in directory (*power*shell):**
[Loop through files in a directory using PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18847145/loop-through-files-in-a-directory-using-powershell)