# How to pass command line arguments to a exported method of an c++ DLL?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, command-line, ace

I am trying to pass the command line arguments from the client console app.CPP to DLL.

subscriber.DLL method was created in VS using code [here](https://github.com/objectcomputing/OpenDDS/blob/master/tools/modeling/tests/Messenger/publisher.cpp)

In my DLL I have a method based on [ace tao](http://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/%7Eschmidt/DOC_ROOT/ACE/docs/ACE-guidelines.html)

```
ACE_TMAIN(int argc, ACE_TCHAR **argv[])
{
 // user code
}
```

ACE_TMAIN is exported in a header file

in the command line, it uses the following command when running them as executables

command --> **Subscriber -DCPSConfigFile [dds_tcp_conf.ini](https://github.com/objectcomputing/OpenDDS/blob/master/examples/DCPS/IntroductionToOpenDDS/dds_tcp_conf.ini)**

the last part is the transport configuration .ini file.

Subscriber is an exe in the above command. but now here it is used as a subscriber.DLL by exporting ACE_TMAIN with arguments.

So how to pass these command line with arguments to DLL from the client console application?

Comment: I assume you call it directly from your application's `int main (int argc, char **argv[])`

Comment: ^ indeed. Is `int main (int argc, char **argv[]) { ACE_TMAIN(argc, argv); }` good enough?

Comment: @drescherjm if I use in my client application main() as int main (int argc, char **argv[]){}.... still how to run the client application?  I don't understand how to use (previous command line Subscriber -DCPSConfigFile dds_tcp_conf.ini)  arguments in my application code, bcz i have to direct DCPSConfigFile to dds_tcp_conf.ini

Comment: I read a little bit more on the ACE. Shouldn't you use their framework? Would your suggestion, of just calling the ACE_TMAIN from your own code work?

Comment: It probably should be more like what @JHBonarius said. With this said I am not sure of your converting this to a dll is the correct approach. However I am not familiar with this library  code.

Comment: @drescherjm project solution was built for VS using given MPC  https://github.com/objectcomputing/OpenDDS/blob/master/tools/modeling/tests/Messenger/Messenger.mpc to output executables.... then I changed the VS project properties to output a dll... and added a header to the dll for method exporting...is this wrong approach? I need to use these subscriber and publishers as dll to a client cosole application

Comment: I tagged for the ace framework.

Comment: @JHBonarius  i am trying to have subscriber and publisher as two DLLs and use them in a c++ console application.... opendds default is like provide subscriber and publisher exe and execute them using the above command line

Comment: Why run these in one application? These sound like two different processes. How do you intend to interweave them? What's wrong with starting them from the command line?

Comment: @JHBonarius  in a production I cant go with commands. that's why I am trying to make two DLLs for publisher and subscriber then run them with a single console app....  is it not possible to do? I am trying to make 2 x DLL and use two threads run ACE_TMAIN  methods in publisher.cpp and subscriber .cpp...  i need to use them as DLLs

Comment: Yes it's possible. But you're modifying the internals of a library, with isn't optimal. You could also look at starting two processes/threads from a C++ program. That way you don't need a console.

Comment: @JHBonarius you meant run 2x exe as it is. in two threads? yeahh c++ program is enough.... how to do it with DLLs?

Comment: @JHBonarius also i feel the ACE_TMAIN arguments are not directly from Subscriber -DCPSConfigFile dds_tcp_conf.ini it is something processed by the command using some internal dds libs.... how to get them into my dlls?

Comment: just keep them as executables... don't modify them. Then: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15440094

Comment: @JHBonarius so you meant the best way to make a normal c++ program and run both exes in two threads with the full command (Subscriber -DCPSConfigFile dds_tcp_conf.ini) using **system() ** ?    is it not practical to make Dlls?

Comment: The subscriber and publisher sound like applications. DLL are libraries. Different purpose. Of course it is possible. But is it good design? Is it necessary?

Comment: @JHBonarius as you said if I go with exe only... my main application.cpp ---> a single DLL (DLL will contain 2 threads and system().to run publisher.exe and separate thread do same for subscriber.exe)  .... is this a good design? rather trying to make publisher dll and subscriber dll? what do you mean by** Is it necessary? **

Comment: did you read my link? you can start applications from C++.

Comment: @JHBonarius in a production environment we cant use commands in command prompt. that's why trying to make a single application to run both publisher and subscriber is this answer to your question is it ** Is it necessary? **

Comment: Are you not reading what I said? You don't need a command prompt. You can start applications from C++. I'm ending this conversation, as you are not listening.