# System copy file with space

Tags: c++, copy

By using system command prompt copy in C++, I could not perform the command as my directory has space in between two character, the 'log' and 'file'. Maybe regular expression may help me solve this problem. But I had no ideas how to do this.

```
system("copy C:\users\person\log file C:\users\person\desktop")
```

Comment: Does putting quotes around the filename with spaces help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9964865/c-system-not-working-when-there-are-spaces-in-two-different-parameters

Comment: Is there a reason not to use `rename` from `<cstdio>` (or other C++ equivalent that I've forgotten)?

Comment: @Barmar nope, it does not works this way.

Comment: @МикроПингвин I don't understand their solution, how to apply to my problem ?

Comment: @user3138965 Try wrapping the whole command in quotations.

Comment: @tabstop: He can use `rename` if he replaces the target directory by the full path to the target file, but then he won't have the original file (he wants to copy the file, not move it).

Comment: @KeithThompson Good point -- don't know why I had rename in my head.

Answer (score 0):

`system("copy \"C:\\users\\person\\log file\" C:\\users\\person\\desktop")`

I haven't tested that, but it should work.

Comment: Note that this example also uses double backslashes `\\`, since they are special characters in C used for escape codes. You must use a double backslash when you are specifying a DOS/Windows filepath.

Answer (score 0):

I believe @tabstop was referring to "[std::rename](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/rename)", which is one solution.  The way that you are copying the file will only work if there is a command called "copy" on the operating system.  If you were to run this program on, say, iOS, it would not work.

Here is a better way of doing this in a C++ way (solution grafted from here: [Copy a file in a sane, safe and efficient way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10195343/copy-a-file-in-an-sane-safe-and-efficient-way))....

```
#include <fstream>

int main(char** argv, int argc) 
{
   std::ifstream  src("C:\\users\\person\\log file", std::ios::binary);
   std::ofstream  dst("C:\\users\\person\\desktop",   std::ios::binary);

   dst << src.rdbuf();
}
```

Don't forget the extra backslashes.  You need them because the backslash is an escape character that will turn on or off functionality (like \n for the newline).

Comment: I remain astounded that `std::rename` is standardised.

Comment: Note that rename doesn't copy the file but moves it. So it is **not** a solution.

Comment: Aren't you trying to write to the directory "Desktop"?