# Lua os.execute with command line arguments

Tags: lua, command-line-arguments, command-prompt

I am running Lua on a Windows 7 machine and I am trying to launch a LabVIEW executable using Lua.

This is an example of the command line input that DOES work:

[image: cmd prompt]

The text I use:

```
"C:\Program Files\National Instruments\LabVIEW 2009\LabVIEW.exe" "C:\Program Files\National Instruments\LabVIEW 2009\examples\viserver\cmdline.llb\CommandLine.vi" -- 4.0
```

However no matter how I try to format this in Lua, it complains:

> 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

I currently have it formatted as the following with no success:

```
local s = [["C:\Program Files\National Instruments\LabVIEW 2009\LabVIEW.exe" "C:\Program Files\National Instruments\LabVIEW 2009\examples\viserver\cmdline.llb\CommandLine.vi" -- 4.0]]
os.execute(s)
```

I need help formatting that local string `s` to do the same as what I typed into the command prompt.

Comment: This probably isn't the issue, but try escaping the backslashes ("C:\\Program Files \\National...")

Comment: The double brackets in Lua disable escape sequences.  I think the issue is a result of the spaces, but the quotes around the paths should resolve that (or so I would think).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some quick reading online suggests that you might need to wrap your command string in an extra set of quotes. Like this I think:

```
[[""C:\Program Files\National Instruments\LabVIEW 2009\LabVIEW.exe" "C:\Program Files\National Instruments\LabVIEW 2009\examples\viserver\cmdline.llb\CommandLine.vi" -- 4.0"]]
```

Comment: I'm not sure where you found that because I searched a good while for a solution, but that definitely solves the problem!

Comment: Don't remember what I searched for exactly but I went through the MSDN page for the `system` function at one point before ending up on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9964865/c-system-not-working-when-there-are-spaces-in-two-different-parameters (which referenced documentation on `cmd` that I'd seen before when looking into command line parsing in `cmd.exe`).