# system() cant run my program because space

Tags: c++

i want run my program 
so i do this program:

```
string zpath1, zpath2, zpath3, zpath3;
        zpath1 = "C:\\Users\\";
        zpath2 = zpath1 + getenv("USERNAME");
        zpath3 = zpath2 + "\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup\\ConsoleApplication23.exe";
system(zpath3.c_str());
```

but i get a problem
'c:\User\adrian\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start' is not knowing...

so i thing the problem is the space between "Start Menu"

how i can solve this problem ?

thank you

Comment: [C++ system() not working when there are spaces in two different parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9964865/c-system-not-working-when-there-are-spaces-in-two-different-parameters)

Comment: Note that hard-coding paths like this is just wrong. Use `SHGetFolderPath(CSIDL_STARTUP)` or `SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Startup)` instead. As for the space issue, you can either 1) add additional quotation characters around the path, or you can convert the path to its short 8.3 version (which won't have any spaces in it) using `GetShortPathName()`

Answer (score 1):

There are three possible solutions, one of two kinds of quotation marks or escape space character

```
zpath1 = "'C:\\Users\\";
//        ^
zpath3 = zpath2 + "\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup\\ConsoleApplication23.exe'";
//                                                                                                                ^
```

```
zpath1 = "\"C:\\Users\\";
//        ^^
zpath3 = zpath2 + "\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup\\ConsoleApplication23.exe\"";
//                                                                                                                ^^
```

```
zpath3 = zpath2 + "\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start^ Menu\\Programs\\Startup\\ConsoleApplication23.exe";
//                                                              ^
```

Thanks to @Eljay. Since the backlash \ is used in Windows as a path component separator, it can't be used as escape char, the carer symbol ^ is used as escape char in Windows command prompt.

Comment: zpath3 would not be the way to escape a space in a path, since the backslash is the path component separator.

Comment: not work :/ it say that the command line doesnt existe :/

Comment: Which of three options have you tried? If the first two, you should move the first quotation mark to zpath1.