# Can't call chcp from the system method

Tags: c, windows, rust, system

Hello I want to run the command `chcp 65001` from my program via the windows api call [system](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/system-wsystem?view=msvc-170).

My program is written in rust but uses external c.

```
extern "C" {
    pub fn system(command: *const u8);
}

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        system("\"\"chcp\" \"65001\"\"".as_ptr());
    }
    // do work
}
```

The call works but I can't manage to format the string to pass into `system` properly.

I tried the following compbinations following to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9964865/c-system-not-working-when-there-are-spaces-in-two-different-parameters) question.

`"\"\"chcp\" \"65001\"\""` (rust format)
With this result: `Parameterformat wrong - "65001"`

I also tried some other variants without success:
`"\"\"chcp\" 65001\""`
result: `Parameterformat wrong - /rustc`

`"\"\"chcp 65001\""`
result `the system can't find the given path`

The first variant seam fine the only problem is that chcp does complain about `\"`

Do you have an Idea how to pass it?

BONUS: Why does '/rustc' appear in variant 2.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Rust strings are not NUL-terminated, so your call to system is reading whatever there is in memory after your string. I guess that's where your `/rustc` comes from.

Comment: Try with `system (CString::new ("chcp 65001").as_ptr())`

Comment: Thank you, you are right. If you post this as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Note that as pointed out by @cerberus the `system` function should strictly speaking take a `*const c_char` and not a `*const u8`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rust strings are not NUL-terminated, so your call to system is reading whatever there is in memory after your string. I guess that's where your `/rustc` comes from. You need to convert your string to a [`CString`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/ffi/struct.CString.html) to ensure that it is properly terminated:

```
system (CString::new ("chcp 65001").unwrap().as_ptr());
```

Comment: This doesn't work as-is, since 1) `CString::new` returns `Result`, 2) after fixing that, `CStr::as_ptr` returns `*const c_char`, which is not always equivalent to `*const u8`.

Comment: And furthermore, if we try to compile this, Rust emits a warning that this call is unsound - https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9d619a42194b0a9fcb7a8fa575d0842c.

Comment: @Cerberus edited to add the `unwrap`. However the call is sound because the temporary is only freed after the call to `system` returns.

Comment: I see, thanks. Was not sure that this would make any difference.